# -bash: matlab: command not found

Tags: macos, matlab, terminal

I am a bit surprised, but I can't run matlab by the terminal of my Mac.
I am trying the command

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab
```

but I get the error

```
-bash: matlab: command not found
```

Listing the contenents of the folder **/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/** I can see the word *matlab* which is supposed to be the executable.
I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Why a negative vote?

Comment: I don't know about the down vote, but that is strange behaviour you are getting.  Are you seeing the executable bit(s) set if you type `ls -al /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab` into the command terminal?  It should look something like `-r-xr-xr-x@`

Comment: It returns: -r-xr-xr-x 1 Met admin 58315 Aug 4 2015 /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab

Comment: What happens when you try `cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/` followed by `./matlab`?

Comment: Does it work by double clicking the icon in your Finder?  If it doesn't, then something is wrong with the executable.

Comment: @informaton It works! Thank you very much! Do you know why this strange behavior?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You should be able to start it with the full path.  However, you can make this simpler by adding `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin` to your system path in your `.bash_profile` so all you have to do is type in `matlab` instead and you can start MATLAB regardless of whatever directory you're in.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but I really don't understand which is the problem.

Comment: Neither do I.  Even the MATLAB documentation says you can specify the full path to the executable and you should be able to run it: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabmac.html

Comment: @Alessandro Excellent!  I'll post it as an answer then.  Sorry I can't be more help on the reason for the issue.  I'm guessing there is something else going on with your profile as raryeng is pointing to.  You can try running `cat ~/.bash_profile` or `cat ~/.bashrc` to double check that there is not another `matlab` reference somewhere, for starters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

`cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/`

and then

`./matlab`

If that, hopefully, works, then you may have a path or environment issue with your O/S which is preventing your call to `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/matlab` from working.

Answer (score 5):

add the installation directory to the PATH environment, for example:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/:$PATH
```

then launch Matlab with

```
matlab
```

in your terminal

Comment: Why do you need the :$PATH. I tried echoing $PATH, and I get a string of other "bin". For instance, /Users/XXXX/google-cloud-sdk/bin. Why would I need to append that to MATLAB's bin? Thankss!!

Comment: this syntax concatenates the new path to existing paths and why you would want to do that depends on how you want to maintain your path variable. I like to not overwrite it since other applications access this variable.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, however, if you used the default folder it would be something like `export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021b/bin/:$PATH`
Additionally, remember about activating `matlab` before via running the `activate_matlab.sh` script located in the installation folder